# How to download a file from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, download

I am working on a website where I want to upload and download data from the server. Upload works fine, but I am unable to download the data. I have a table named `upload` with columns: `uplaod_name`, `sub_name`, `semester_id`, `date` and `file_content`. Here is the form from which I am downloading data:

```
<?php

include_once("functions.php");
$query="SELECT * from uploads";
$rs = execute_query($query);

?>
<form  action="s_downfinl.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="groove" cellpadding="15px">
<tr>
<td>Subject Name</td>
<td>upload name</td>
<td>Download</td>
</tr>
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
echo "<tr><td>";
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($row);
//echo "</pre>";
echo $row['sub_name']."</td><td>";  
echo $row['upload_name']."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='s_downfinl.php?nama=". $row['file_content']."'>download</a></td>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
</form>
```

and the s_downfinl.php file for downloading the file:

```
<?php
include_once("functions.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE sub_name = $sub_name";
$name= $_POST['nama'];
download($name);
$rs = execute_query($query);

function download($name){
$file = $nama_fail;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm confused why you would be storing the file contents in the DB as opposed to just uploading the file to the server and storing the file path in the DB. Could you elaborate on what the contents of the file is and what the final output you would like is?

Comment: am working on a academic type of website where teachers would upload files like ppt lectures , pdf and word docs and students would login and download them for themselves. its my semester project actually

Comment: In which case I would advise you to simply upload the files to some directory on your server and for each row in your DB save the `file_path` instead of the `file_contents`. Then you can just provide a download link to the filepath.

Comment: Please correct your question's code, it has multiple errors and it is incomplete. For example the form's action="s_downfinl.php" but you write that the name of the php file where form data are posted is s_downfinal.php also in the form the method is post but you use GET in order to retrieve the variable. Also try to post only the sub_name and run a query in s_downfinal.php like this select * from uploads where sub_name=$subname

Comment: You seem to use a variable `$file_content` for the href part of the link in the first part of the code. I can't see where that variable is set. Are we sort of doing your homework for you?

Comment: @RST file_content is the attribute in the table in which the file is saved while uploading. i will upload the uploading file if you want. and NO you are not doing my homework its called helping others when they are stuck badly :P

Comment: I would expect at least something like `$file_content = $row['file_content'];`

Comment: done the editing it shows alot of scrumbled data in the table and when i click download link it browse to the s_downfinl.php bt its a blank page doing nothing

Comment: I wasn't saying it would solve the issue. The question is why are you showing file_content while you probably need upload_name. That is the part you want to send to the other php file. Still feel like we are doing your homework. You have not tested/debugged this code thoroughly.

Comment: can anybody help please??

Comment: Is that correct: `function download($name){
$file = $nama_fail; ...` with `nama_fail` ??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `$sub_name` variable in your `where` clause `WHERE sub_name = $sub_name` - if that is a string (*which I am under the impression it is*), it needs to be quoted `WHERE sub_name = '$sub_name'`. Using `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` would/should trigger a syntax error.

At this point, it's unsure where and how that variable is defined.

Plus this `$_POST['nama']` that should be a GET as per `s_downfinl.php?nama`.

Check for errors using error reporting while testing.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Also use [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) for your query, to see if your query failed.

---

Footnotes:

- `$nama_fail` is undefined as per your posted code, therefore you may need to elaborate on that, same thing for `$sub_name`.

Have a look at these examples on downloading files from a database.

- [Download files from MYSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15560441/)
  One of the answers in that question https://stackoverflow.com/a/15560485/ looks to be a working example. Base yourself on that example, and try it without your additional function(s) `function download($name){
  $file = $nama_fail; ...}`.
- http://php.about.com/od/phpbasics/ss/mysql_files_6.htm
- http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=h110/pdfget.php

They may give you ideas/help.