# Is it possible to resume a direct-download, from MySQL database, with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, http, download

Many days ago, I have read some useful posts on **Stack Overflow**; for instance:

- [Download files from MYSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560441/download-files-from-mysql-database)
- [How do I download a file using PHP and Mysql DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329586/how-do-i-download-a-file-using-php-and-mysql-db)

These posts show me: the way to make a simple storage system, which allows user to download file, from MySQL database, with PHP.

---

These scripts are working fine;. and, I have used some functions with those scripts:

- `base64_encode();`: when uploading a file.
- `base64_decode();`: when downloading a file.

Imagine, the connection is lost (or `Cancel` button is pressed); if I try to resume this downloading, the [download manager](https://superuser.com/tags/download-manager/hot) will start the downloading at the **beginning**.

[image: IDM]

I know: [this is not a download manager problem](https://superuser.com/questions/320402/resuming-a-download-using-internet-download-manager/387352).

---

This is the **meaningless** way, which you **should not** advise me:

- **Step 1.** Export the file-content from database to server-disk.
- **Step 2.** Assign the download-link with the *tempratory file* (in **Step 1.**).
- **Step 3.** Allow users to download file with the `fake-link`.
- **Step 4.** Delete the *tempratory file*, if users have downloaded this file completely.

I want to download file from database, **directly**. So, this way is really **crazy**.

---

Can you tell me: "*Is it possible to resume a direct-download, from MySQL database, with PHP?*". And, if the answer is: "`Yes`"; please tell me your way ...

Comment: If my question is not clear, please patient to comment below. I will see it; then, I will try to explain more.

Comment: "I have used some functions to make it be more secure:" "base64_encode()" --- it's unlikely `base64` makes anything "more secure"

Comment: The answer to your question though is: check the http `Range` header.

Comment: one of the reasons why storing files in the database is almost always a bad idea

Comment: @YeuSeChia because it's likely that what you need can be easier and more resource-efficient achievable with filesystem-based storage.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/files-in-the-database-or-not

Comment: @YeuSeChia "Simple code for demonstration?" --- google for it, there are millions of examples in the net.

Comment: I agree with @zerkms. If you are using base64 to store data you are most likely doing it wrong.

Comment: Even that is better than storing base64 encoded data in the database.